# How to use -d in ntfsundelete?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, centos, data-recovery

As far as I can tell from the manpage of `ntfsundelete` getting a file back is done with e.g.

```
ntfsundelete /dev/sdb3 -u -m important.txt
```

which would undelete the file in-place. If I don't want in-place mode I see this option

```
-d, --destination DIR  Destination directory
```

but when I use it `-d /tmp/win` it thinks it is a regex.

How should `-d` be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this blog with a title posted: [ntfsundelete - Undeleting NTFS files](http://kwlug.org/node/649), and the following example:

```
$ sudo ntfsundelete /dev/sda2 -u -m '*.mp3' -p 100 -t 5m \
     -d /media/externalExt3/undeleted
```

Are you using `sudo` when you run your command?

Answer (score 2):

I'm the co-author (h. ohmacht) of `ntfsundelete`. An example usage is:

```
ntfsundelete -u -m "*" -d "/root/recovery" /dev/sda1
```

will recover *any* file on `/dev/sda1` to directory `/root/recovery`; this is the best way.